# Fade in and fade out my text using Jquery, and also display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I kind of have 2 questions.One... I wish to fade in and fade out my text when I click on the images I have on my site. I very fortunately got to get toggle working thanks to the community here, but now I'm curious as to how I can get fadeIn and fadeOut working.

Also I wish to have my text be hidden or not visible until the moment I actually click on the image. One click of the image should cause the text to fade in. If I click the image again, I would like the text to fade out.

Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>JOHN DOE Project</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="something_style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".clickToHideClass").click(function () {
         // now toggle only the 'p' under 'this'
         $('p', $(this)).toggle();
     });
 });


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hover(function(){

    $("p").css("font-style","italic");
    $("p").css("color", "pink");
    $("p").css("font-weight", "bold");


    },function(){

    $("p").css("color","normal");
    $("p").css("font-style", "normal");
    $("p").css("font-weight", "normal");

  });
});
</script>

<body> 
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="outerWrapper">
 <div id="header"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/johndoe?fref=ts"><img src=" PUT SOMETHING HERE FOR IMAGE OF YOUR BANNER OR SOMETHING " alt="JohnDoe" width="366" height="66" /></a>

</div>
<div id="topNavigation"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="outerWrapper">
        <div id="contentWrapperhome">
            <div class="clickToHideClass" id = 'col1'><a><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="JohnDoe" width="251" height="251" /></a>

                <div id="text">
                     <h1><a>Language and the World</a></h1>

                    <p><a>An aspiration and dream of mine</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clickToHideClass" id = 'col1'><a><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="JohnDoe" width="251" height="251" />
     </a>

                <div id="text">
                     <h1><a>Music and Drama</a></h1>

                    <p><a>Keeps me pumping on every hour of the day!</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>


    <div id="col1" class = "clickToHideClass"><a><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="JohnDoe" width="251" height="251">
      </a><div id="text">



      <h1><a>Friendship</a></h1>
      <p><a> Without them I really wouldn't know Myself</a></a></p>
    </div></div>

  </div>
  </div></div>
  <div id="outerWrapper">
  <div id="footer"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/johndoe?fref=ts">Contact information</a> | <a href="https://www.facebook.com/johndoe?fref=ts">Website</a> | <a href="https://www.facebook.com/johndoe?fref=ts">Terms</a> | <a href="https://www.facebook.com/johndoe?fref=ts">Site by </a></div>
</div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is part of the CSS:

```
#text p a {
text-decoration: none;

}
```

In the css I want to enter, "display:none", but doing that will cause the toggle to not work.

Comment: `.toggle()` is depreciated by the way

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, try this:

```
$(".clickToHideClass img").click(function() {
    $(this).find("#text").fadeToggle();
});
```